# Can't install Firefox beta in silent mode

Tags: firefox, testing, continuous-integration

I need for `CI` to download beta version of `Firefox`,install it and use the binary file for my tests.

Can't find silent install for beta version.

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Travis-CI`, you can use the Firefox addon: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/firefox/#Version-aliases

Otherwise, you can easily write a script to download it, see this [README](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/latest-beta/README.txt) that explains how.
Basically, you can do something like `wget -O firefox.tar.bz2 "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-beta-latest&os=linux64&lang=en-US"`

There's also a Node.js module (with a CLI) to download Firefox, I don't know if it's maintained: https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/mozilla-download.

This Python library is definitely maintained: https://github.com/mozilla/mozdownload.

Comment: Gr8.  What about install in silent?